# Custom NSLog Method ( Variadic )

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, ios6, variadic-functions

I am trying to create a custom `NSLog()` method , `DNSLog()` , which executes the `NSLog` only if the debug variable is true.

```
-(void)DNSLog:(NSString *)formatString, ...
{
    if(debug){
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, formatString);
        NSLog([[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString arguments:args]);
        va_end(args);
    }
}
```

But when I try calling it using

```
DNSLog(@"Hello %d",x);
```

I receive a compilation error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_DZNSLog", referenced from:
      -[RestaurantInfoViewController viewDidLoad] in RestaurantInfoViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have used this as a reference : http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I think you shall be learning C before trying to get into advanced stuff. It seems you can't even differentiate between the syntax of a C function and an Objective-C method...

Comment: Furthermore, your code is vulnerable to format string attacks/errors. You should use `NSLogv(formatString, args);` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have confused *methods* and *functions* - Objective-C has both. `NSLog` is a standard function so you call it as `NSLog(...)`. You have defined a method:

```
-(void)DNSLog:(NSString *)formatString, ...
```

but tried to call it as a function. To call your method you need to do:

```
[self DNSLog:@"Hello %d", x];
```

As your code compiles you must have a global or instance `debug` variable. If it is a *global* then you could define `DNSLog` as a function (this won't work if `debug` is an instance variable as only methods can directly access those). The function would start:

```
 void DNSLog(NSString *formatString, ...)
```

The body of the function will be the same as for the method.

`NSLog` also has an attribute, `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION`, on it to tell the compiler that it takes a format string as an argument, seeing this the compiler will check the format string and arguments to see that they match. To do this for your method or function write:

```
-(void)DNSLog:(NSString *)formatString, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

or:

```
void DNSLog(NSString *formatString, ...)  NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2);
```

in the interface or header file.

HTH.

Comment: @Kyuubi - Yes you figured some of this out yourself while I was away typing this in, don't forget the `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` though - it helps a lot.

Comment: Got it. Appended the same to my function.

Comment: What does the number 1 and 2 mean in NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2)

Comment: @DongfangZhu - the first number identifies the argument that is the format string, the second the number Identifies the first format argument, which is usually one more than the first number but it need not be. For example if `DNSLog` took an additional first argument, say a Boolean to determine whether it should actually print, with the format string becoming the 2nd argument and the first value to format becoming the 3rd, then you would need `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(2,3)`

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using a custom method, try adding this macro to your app, perhaps in your .pch file.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define MyLog(x, ...) NSLog(@"%s %d: " x, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define MyLog(x, ...)
#endif
```

This will run a custom log I call MyLog when in debug mode, and when in release, it wont do anything. It also prints out some other useful information like the file and line number of the log.

Comment: Actually his question was about only logging when "the debug variable is true."  His code seems to indicate that he has a separate debug variable he is controlling.  Also, H2CO3 is just calling it the way he sees it.  I feel the same way.  I rarely provide code in answers myself because I know if I do people will just copy and paste it and then be at a loss when it doesn't work exactly as written.  I feel that people should *understand* the code they are writing.

Comment: Well then isn't the solution to post an answer to help inform him so that he can understand it? Perhaps we create a post that actually helps op learn and implement this method. And to add to that, sharing a different way to do something shouldn't be wrong, but I see your point now.

Comment: Thanks. That works as well! 
But in the future I might have a complex boolean expression and a nested if-else in the Log Function, so was trying to implement a new function all together, instead of a MACRO.

Answer (score 11):

Thank You everyone for your extremely 'valuable', 'encouraging' and 'supporting' answers to a beginner.

I found my mistake and here is the corrected working code :

```
void ZNSLog(NSString *format, ...){
    if(!ENABLE_DEBUGGING)
        return;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSLogv(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

ZNSLog(@"Hello");
```

The previous method I was using was an Objective C method

```
-(void)DNSLog:(NSString *)formatString, ...
```

which I was trying to call using a C function Call.